# Making a rails 7 stimulus controller handle values dynamically

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, leaflet

while `leaflet` can be installed and a map generated, with

```
./bin/importmap pin leaflet
```

manually adding the `leaflet.css` file to `assets/stylesheets` and images to the `public/images` directory,

a stimulus controller is set with static values.

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ "placeholder" ]

  connect(){
    import("leaflet").then( L => {
      this.map = L.map(this.placeholderTarget,{zoomDelta:0.5,zoomSnap:0.5}).setView([ 47.1960, 9.023 ], 10);

      var base_map = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      }).addTo(this.map);
      var marker1 = L.marker([47.4, 8.9]).addTo(this.map);
      var marker2 = L.marker([47.0, 9.3]).addTo(this.map);
    });
  }

  disconnect(){
    this.map.remove()
  }

}
```

The coordinates will be elsewhere on the page.

How should this controller then be cast assuming the document will have an `id` for 'lat_1', 'lon_1', 'lat_2', 'lon_2', 'zoom', 'lat_marker_1', 'lon_marker_1', 'lat_marker_2', 'lon_marker_2'

Answer (score 2):

This is an XY problem.
It goes to say that for pretty much any programming langauge/framework that if you're using identifiers (variable names, ids, attribute etc) that end with `_n` you're doing it wrong and should be using a list/array/map/hash/object instead.

If you want to pass a bunch of Map markers through the DOM just use an element such as a list and data attributes:

```erb
<ul id="cities">
  <li data-lat="40.781944" data-lon="-73.966111">New York</li>
  <li data-lat="19.076111" data-lon="72.87751">Mumbai</li>
  <li data-lat="50.45" data-lon="30.523333">Kyiv</li>
</ul>
```

This mostly makes sense if your displaying the same data on the page in for example a table. Otherwise you might want to consider setting up a route which provides the data as JSON.

You can also use custom elements if you want like [vue-leaflet does](https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/components/LMarker.html#demo).

If you then want to add these markers to the map you just loop through the elements:

```
let cities = document.getElementById('cities');
for (const city of cities.children) {
  let marker = L.marker([city.dataSet.lat, city.dataSet.lon]);
  marker.addTo(this.map);
}
```

Remember that you don't have to (or want to) assign ids to everything in the DOM - that's just a beginner crutch that makes you write bad JS. The document is a data structure that can be grouped, traversed and selected.